# Primefaces get all data in lazy model

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lazy-loading, data-export

I am using lazy model for datatable in Primefaces. For exporting I want to get all data, by that I mean the data that is used for counting rows.

I can get all data that is shown currently on datatable page by using:

```
List<Info> data = (List<Info>) lazyModel.getWrappedData();
```

but there may be more data on more pages. Is there any method similiar to just mentioned one to get all data from datatable?

I've tried using this, but this would always return null:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .findComponent(":form:infoTable");
List<Info> data = dataTable.getFilteredValue();
```

Another way I've tried is to just make nearly the same query I am making for counting rows, with difference being that I get list of objects, not number of rows, but for that I also need a filter. If this could be a solution, how do I get a filter that I am using for lazy loading?

Generally, how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to get a filter. 
I've fetched my custom filter from lazy model, and used it to query from overriden load method, so the only difference is that I did not use arguments first and page size.

Nothing really new to show in solution, I just had to get the filter:

```
Map<String, Object> filters = ((MyLazyDataModel) lazyModel).getFilters().getFilters();
```